# How to getRowIndex of google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get row index of `CUS10003` or get range something like `getRange[id,getLasColum]` with `var id = "CUS10003"`

I'm using google script app. Thank!

[image]

Comment: Try using TextFinder

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: If  it's arranged alphabetically, then  the row is always the id+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small demo code to explain a basic approach:

```
function myDemoFunction() {
  var keyValue = 'CUS10003';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var keys = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  keys = keys.map(function(v) {return v[0];});
  var row = keys.indexOf(keyValue) + 2;
  if (row > 1) {
    Logger.log(row); // This is a row number for the key value
    var keyCell = sheet.getRange(row, 1);

    var col = keyCell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
    Logger.log(col); // This is the last column for key row (if variable)

    var keyRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, col);  // Entire key range
    Logger.log(keyRange.getA1Notation());
  } else {
    Logger.log('Key not found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I found another way, let you see and comment to me ^^    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var source =  ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  var lr = source.getLastRow()
  var lookupRangeValues = source.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var id = "CUS10004";
  
  for(var i = 0; i < lookupRangeValues.length; i++){
    
    if(lookupRangeValues[i] == id){
 
       Logger.log(lookupRangeValues[i]);//find
  
    }
  }

Comment: Yes, this way is correct too. The only doubt is about comparison: `lookupRangeValues[i] == id`. Be attentive, the left part is array! Because the method `Range.getValues()` returns 2D arrays.